# Tar exit code non-zero

Tags: backup, tar

I'm trying to build a backup script that creates a full tarball from my system each night. To do this I followed the tutorial [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR).

So to test it out I decided to create a manual backup:

```
tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --one-file-system /
```

When I try to run this command I get the error:

```
tar: /run/: file is on a different filesystem; not dumped
```

This results in an exit code of 1. However, I want to run this command in a script and if the returncode is `0` I want to move the output file, otherwise delete it. If I understand correctly from the the tutorial linked above the `--one-file-system` implies that `/run/` is ignored.  But why do I get the error then?

For completness sake, the script (WIP) is shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Location to store backups
STORAGE=/media/storage/backups/full
# Current date
DATE=$(date +"%d.%m.%YT%H.%M")
TAR="$DATE.tar.gz"


# Check if the file already exists. Should never be the case though.
if [ ! -f /tmp/$TAR ]; then

    echo "Changing dir to /"
    cd /
    # Create tarball
    echo "Creating tarball"
    tar -cvpzf /tmp/$TAR --exclude=/tmp/$TAR --one-file-system /
    retcode=$?

    echo "Exit status: $retcode"

    if [ $retcode = 0 ] ; then
        echo "Moving file.."
        # Move the file
        mv /tmp/$TAR $STORAGE/$TAR
        echo "Done!"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: You are mistaken; you get the message about the path being ignored because you asked tar to be verbose with the -v switch.  That does not cause it to have a non zero exit status.  What can cause a non zero exit status however, is when it warns that the contents of a file changed while it was backing it up, which happens when you are trying to backup a filesystem that is in active use.

Comment: Aha, this makes sense. I was indeed under the presumption that the ignore error was causing the exit code `1`. Thank you. If you post this as an answer I will gladly accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare `--one-file-system` first before the exclusion rule. There is note from the same guide you followed.

> If you want to exclude all other mounts other than the current - by
>   this I mean partitions mounted to directories - then use the
>   --one-file-system option appended before the exclusion rules. This has the effect of stopping tar from crossing into any other mounts in any
>   directory including /mnt or /media.

Comment: That is indeed the case, but I do not explicitly ignore any directories like `bin` or `sys`. These ignores are implied by the `--one-file-system`. So in fact it is a verbatim copy of the command stated in the guide.

Comment: I was referring to your `--exclude=/tmp/$TAR`